# Link in Google results will be get or post

Tags: post, get

I just want to know whether on clicking the results of Google search will be resulting in a get request or post request.

Answer (score 0):

Open debugger/inspect element on browser. Choose Net tab. Click on a result and see for yourself. It is GET.

Comment: so does it mean if in my action i reject all get requests/ accept only post requests, when i click on the google link it will be redirecting to error page?